# Remove hover from meta-title wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, hover, wordpress-theming

I want to remove the hover effect from the meta "19 De Março De 2021| ReMederi| 0 Comentário", but I cant find it on the css.

```
.post-box .entry-meta a {
  color: #7141b1;
}
```

Comment: Please dont post links that can be broken in future. Show us parts of your code you think are problematic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple css rule would do it, similar to:

```
 .entry-meta a:hover{color:inherit}
```

Comment: Thank you so much i just add one thing and it worked!
`.post-box .entry-meta a:hover{
 color:inherit
}`